# CanvasJs dynamic Data with PHP, mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sikm.jpg)

Hello i have obstacle for my chart from CanvasJs.

I just put simple code to get simple chart with parameter target and actual, i found error in dataPoints: i think the problem just wrong statements.

this my error code:

> dataPoints:   [

```
<?PHP $mkmi3= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monthkpimontindv WHERE idKpiDetIndv='$q'");

    While ($mkmi4= mysql_fetch_assoc($mkmi3)) 

        {

            echo "{ label: ".$mkmi4['period'].", y: ".$mkmi4['actual']." },\n";

        }
?>
```

> ```
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we can display `MySQL` data in `CanvasJS`, Try like this.

Here, Create a PHP service that returns data in JSON format. HTML page that does AJAX request to the server and fetches the data. After getting the data, it renders a Chart.

**PHP Service to return JSON Data**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","canvasjssampledb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else
{
    $data_points = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sales");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
        $point = array("label" => $row['product'] , "y" => $row['total_sales']);

        array_push($data_points, $point);        
    }

    echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**HTML Page to Fetch Data and render Chart**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="canvasjs.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    data: [
                        {
                            dataPoints: result
                        }
                    ]
                });

                chart.render();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Note:: IE8- is supported in v1.3 and above.

Comment: hi please help me again, my problem solve with your answer but, if i want select my sales with idEmp something like that how can i wrote the code?

Comment: in example for $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sales where idEmp='$id'");

Comment: how to make $id in my example dyanamic?

Comment: i didn't get you. But i hope this is what you meant?!! `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE idEMP= ".$id ;` and change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `fetch_assoc`.

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you again, please see my screenshoot, i have a chart who have different category value if your example code using sales table, if i have another chart and then have where value in idEmp so can i getJson data from the HTML Page to Fetch Data and render Chart?